# Can't install any linux distros. Grub Boot loader installation freezes and keyboard and mouse won't work

Tags: debian, grub, kali-linux, bootrepair

I tried to install several Linux Distros but just Debian 10 and Kali Linux made it to the installation screen. Other ones just stuck at the loading screen. I tried several ways of Rufus settings but to no avail.
Kali and Debian were installed but at the Grub Boot Loader installation screen just freezes and I can't use any key on keyboard or mouse.
My laptop is Acer Travelmate 4750G with intel core i5 cpu, 8gb ram and nvidia Gforce GT520M. There is no settings for UEFI boot in it. It is a pretty old laptop.
I tried to use Bood Repair Live Disk but I just could make it work in legacy mode and it says I should use EFI session.
Is there a way I can install Grub?
And by the way no Live version of Linux can be load to use them

[https://pasteboard.co/IDAYBce.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9UUY.jpg)

[https://pasteboard.co/IDAZidX.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9UUY.jpg)

[https://pasteboard.co/IDAZBd9.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9UUY.jpg)

[https://pasteboard.co/IDAZQzc.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9UUY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked another question on superuser sometime after this one and received an answer which applies to this question too. I share it here:
[Link to the answer](https://superuser.com/a/1537203/1064154)

> Boot from the stick, press Shift to show grub, press "e" to edit, add "acpi=off" after "quiet splash", save edit from grub, proceed with boot WITHOUT rebooting, then tell us.

And in the comments I added this part:

> In my case pressing c and typing "acpi=off" worked.

By doing what was suggested I could boot the live usb and install the distro I wanted.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Update BIOS](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/3519;). to latest version.
2. [Set boot to UEFI](https://us.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27103) according to directions.
3. Select a USB flash drive between 8 & 16 GB. Large drives formatted exFAT may not work.
4. Download the ISO in advance to avoid dropout issues.
5. Use Rufus to make either MBR (general purpose) or GPT partition, if MBR fails to work.
6. Most reliable is to use the installation media to delete all partitions, wiping any data and OS, and to create partitions and install without intervention, other than selecting whether to include third-party tools.

[image: Rufus usage]

My experience with Ubuntu, Lubuntu and other Debian flavors is that complete installation with third-party software included takes less than 30 minutes, even on much older machines than yours. Please let us know if this works for you.

Comment: The problem is I can't update BIOS. The exe file does nothing. It just turns off the laptop and the BIOS version stays the same.

Comment: You might get by with the old BIOS. If you want to update BIOS, it needs to run from Windows, e.g. WnRE or WinPE. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/144526/how-to-flash-a-bios-when-only-a-windows-binary-is-provided