# How to install Lubuntu 19.10 on an only-BIOS system

Tags: bios, lubuntu

I have tried to install Lubuntu 19.10 on my machine but I've never succeeded. There are always these frozen screens in below:  [image]

Today I tried using dd command to copy Lubuntu on a usb stick and this happened.
Before that I used rufus for this purpose which ended in frozen state.

My system's motherboard only has BIOS and no UEFI.
The disk partitions are of MBR type.
 
What should I do?

**Puppy Linux 8** could be installed on my system although. Where I could not install any other Linux Distros.

My laptop:

Acer TravelMate 4750G
Intel Core i5-2450M
Nvidia GeForce GT 520M with 1 GB Dedicated VRAM
8 GB RAM
Western Digital Green WDS240G2G0A Internal SSD Drive 240GB

**Update:**
After changing to AHCI:
[image]
It freezes here and cpu starts to make louder noises.

Comment: If you are going to install an OS on a BIOS/MBR PC, then the ISO must be copied onto your USB stick accordingly. Go into your BIOS and make sure your SATA is on AHCI. Secondly, there have been issues with Ubuntu (all versions) not installing correcty on Acer TravelMate laptop, for some reason or other. You don't have an Optane SSD+HDD combo installed, by chance? (You mention your SSD, not the possible presence of an added hard drive)

Comment: @Didier no just the ssd is present

Comment: How long does your computer stay in the state we see on the picture before you interrupt it? There's usually a timeout for those things in Linux: if the system or installer fails to respond, a reboot is initiated to clear the RAM and start again. Have you tried with an older version of Lubuntu, say, 19.04? Then upgrade once installed?

Comment: @Didier It stays like this until I turn off the laptop. Nothing works in this state and oushing buttons doesn't do anything. I've tried ubuntu 18.04 before. But the same happened. After I changed to AHCI the process went a little further but then it froze again.

Comment: Could be that your CPU is throttling because it's overheating, too, but from the error message in your picture, I doubt it. Have you tried Unetbootin to copy your ISO on your USB stick? It's less picky than Rufus et al on the ISO it copies, and faster too. I like Rufus to copy Windows ISOs on USB, but for Linux, I prefer Unetbootin.

Comment: @Didier I used Unetbootin but the same result came up. I updated the post with a new picture after changing to AHCI. It gets stuck there and I have to turn the laptop off to use it again.

Comment: You mention Puppy Linux, but it's live distro, it's not meant to be installed per se, just running from RAM. When you start your USB stick to install Ubuntu, do you see grub, the bootloader? Sometimes, it's set on "quiet" and will take you directly to the Ubuntu welcome screen with the dots moving left to right. Press Shift when you boot from the stick, and find the line that says "quiet splash". You can edit grub by pressing "e". Do that, and add "acpi=off" at the end of the "quiet splash" line, after a space, then press F10 to save those settings and boot from them.

Comment: Well I installed the full version of puppy and it was successful. No copying on ram. Yes I see grub.

Comment: @Didier When I add acpi=off to the line and press f10 an empty screen appears and nothing happens

Comment: Have you tried to reboot your USB stick with those settings (acpi=off)?

Comment: @Didier If I press f10 the blank screen happens and then I turn off the pc. When I start the machine, the change in the grub is not there. Is there a way to reboot after changing the grub code?

Comment: It should be saved as long as you're running the installer. It doesn't get saved if you reboot your PC, though, unless you've set persistence on the USB when you made it. Few programs propose that option. Only one comes to mind: LinuxLive USB Creator (here: https://www.linuxliveusb.com/fr/home) that'll create a small storage partition on your USB stick to save settings and data between reboots. Back to your problem: boot from the stick, press Shift to show grub, press "e" to edit, add "acpi=off" after "quiet splash", save edit from grub, proceed with boot WITHOUT rebooting, then tell us.

Comment: I thought if I change the grub option in cli mode it could happen. I changed acpi in grub cli and it did the trick. Now I'm in live lubuntu. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Didier If you'd be so kind to make an answer here I will accept it

Comment: done. And glad to know you're out of the woods!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot from the stick, press Shift to show grub, press "e" to edit, add "acpi=off" after "quiet splash", save edit from grub, proceed with boot WITHOUT rebooting, then tell us.

Comment: In my case pressing c and typing "acpi=off" worked. Thanks again